# Habilitar Tab desde otro Tab en javafx

Tags: javafx

Necesito de vuestra ayuda:

Tengo una aplicación en la que quiero habilitar un `Tab` al seleccionar una fila de una tabla, esto es algo sencillo, pero me ha surgido una complicación, ya que cada `Tab`  tiene su FXML y controlador de forma independiente.

Tengo un `TabPane` principal con su FXML en el que incluyo los otros FXML con los `Tab` y cada uno tiene su controlador (subcontroller).

EL `Tab` seleccionado por defecto tiene una tabla en la que se listan clientes, y al seleccionar uno, quiero habilitar los otros `Tab's` que están deshabilitados por defecto (Tienen datos de clientes que se muestran cuando selecciono un cliente, sino quedan desactivados).

Controlo el cambio de `Tab` desde el controlador principal donde está el TabPane y paso valores entre ellos sin problemas, pero no soy capaz de habilitar y deshabilitar los `Tab`.

TabPane donde inlcuyo los Tab's

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabPaneClientes" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="tabClientesEdicion" closable="false" text="Edicion">
                <content>
                    <fx:include fx:id="tabEdicion" source="TabClientesEdicionVista.fxml" />
                </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="tabClientesFactura" closable="false" text="Facturas">
                <content>
                    <fx:include fx:id="tabFactura" source="TabClientesFacturaVista.fxml" />
                </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="tabClientesDevolucion" closable="false" text="Devoluciones">
                <content>
                    <fx:include fx:id="tabDevolucion" source="TabClientesDevolucionVista.fxml" />
                </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
    </TabPane>
```

¿Como podría solventarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Ya he dado con la solución, he comunicado los controladores de los fxml incluidos con el principal (bastante obvio, pero no lo había pensado), os paso un enlace donde he obtenido la solución. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgubWgheboI